# Node webkit package not opening properly from double click in OSX Finder

Tags: node-webkit

I've created a very simple app.nw package with the minimal 'hello world' setup, according to [nw.js/README.md](https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/). It consists of only two files:

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Hello World!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello World!</h1>
    We are using node.js <script>document.write(process.version)</script>.
  </body>
</html>
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "nw-demo",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "main": "index.html"
}
```

It works fine when run from the console like this:

`/Applications/nwjs.app/Contents/MacOS/nwjs myapp.nw`

However when I double click `myapp.nw` in the Finder it opens the default nwjs files, not my app.

I am developing an app for non-technical users who will not open the Terminal. We can have them download and install nwjs.app into their Applications folder, but then we need them to be able to just download and double click the app package.

I was able to get my app to execute from a double click in the Finder by copying `myapp.nw` package into the `Resources` directory of a copy of nwjs.app and renaming it to `app.nw` as per [nwjs packaging documentation](https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/wiki/How-to-package-and-distribute-your-apps), however this integrates our custom code into the very large nwjs.app distributable (93.8MB). This is an unacceptable size to ask our users to download each time.

**How can I enable my node webkit package (which contains only our specific application code and assets) to be opened directly from OSX Finder?**

Answer (score 0):

You need to pack the file into an executable. For more information, check out [this guide](https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/wiki/how-to-package-and-distribute-your-apps) on the project git.

My recommendation is that you won't do it manually. Instead use [grunt](http://gruntjs.com/) to pack your files. To get started, use [yeoman](http://yeoman.io/) and [generator-node-webkit](https://www.npmjs.com/package/generator-node-webkit) for a basic project layout and build script.

Then, making the executable is easy as:

```
grunt dist-mac
```

Comment: You've linked to the same packaging documentation I linked to in my question and the tools you recommend are great for automating the manual build process I outlined in my question, but also still result in a large executable. The question is whether there is a way to create a small executable that opens with the generic nwjs.app installed to the users Applications.

Comment: @RobertCarterMills You mean creating an installer?

Comment: Basically I'm just trying to minimize what our users have to download.  It appears there is no getting around the fact that node-webkit is large. I think the solution is to just package our app into an executable, as Kuf suggested, and then implement self updating functionality within the app so users will not have to re-download the entire app as we iterate on its development.

Comment: @RobertCarterMills Yea, I experiences the same issue. For now each updated download the full executable (zipped - about 42MB), but I plan later to download only the `app.nw` folder. Since our updates are quite rare, we pushed it for now.